# Does OrientDB HTTP API provide functionality to drop a database?

Tags: rest, api, http, orientdb, drop-database

Does OrientDB HTTP API provide functionality to drop a database?

I couldnot find any reference for the same in the OrientDB documentation related to its HTTP API 
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/OrientDB-REST.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Postman, and you can do that using `DELETE` command like this:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards